# Sequence Puzzle

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If $a_{0}$= 1 , $a_{1}=1,$ $a_{n}=a_{n-1}a_{n-2}+1$for $n>1$

then

A) $a_{465}$ is odd and $a_{466}$ is even

B) $a_{465}$ is odd and $a_{466}$ is odd

C) $a_{465}$ is even and $a_{466}$ is even

D) $a_{465}$ is odd and $a_{466}$ is odd

How to solve such a sum?

Comment: The way to solve it is to calculate $a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots$, look for a pattern, use induction to prove the pattern goes on forever, and then see what it tells you about the numbers you want.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Write out the first few terms and observe the parities:

- If $a_k$ is even, then $a_{k + 1}$ is odd, since it's of the form (even + odd).
- If $a_k$ is odd and $a_{k - 1}$ is even, then $a_{k + 1}$ is also odd, since it's still of the same form.
- If $a_k$ is odd and $a_{k - 1}$ is odd, then $a_{k + 1}$ is of the form (odd)(odd) + odd = even, so $a_{k + 1}$ is even.

So every third sequence term is even.